# Access JIRA API from Excel with VBA-Web

Tags: vba, excel, rest, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to access the `JIRA API` from Excel. Using the `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0` object works fine but using the `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` from the `VBA-Web WebClient` does not.

This works fine:

```
Function getJiraSessionId()

Set JiraAuth = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

With JiraAuth
    .Open "POST", "https://<our JIRA server>/tracker/rest/auth/1/session", False
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Jira-Automation"
    .Send " {""username"" : ""...."", ""password"" : ""....""} "
    sErg = .ResponseText
End With
...    
End Function
```

This does not:

```
Function JiraLogin()

    Dim JiraClient As New WebClient
    JiraClient.BaseUrl = "https://<our JIRA server>/tracker/"
    JiraClient.Insecure = True
    JiraClient.TimeoutMs = 50000

    Dim Abruf As New WebRequest
    Abruf.Resource = "rest/auth/1/session"
    Abruf.Method = WebMethod.HttpPost
    Abruf.Format = WebFormat.Json
    Abruf.UserAgent = "Jira-Automation"


    Set Body = New Dictionary
    Body.Add "username", "...."
    Body.Add "password", "...."
    Set Abruf.Body = Body

    Dim Response As WebResponse
    Set Response = JiraClient.Execute(Abruf)
    ...
End Function
```

The error message is:

> ERROR - WebClient.Execute: -2147210493 (11011 / 80042b03), An error occurred during execute
>   -2147012739 (80072f7d): Im Support des sicheren Channels ist ein Fehler aufgetreten

I want to use `VBA-Web` because of its great tools but I can't. Any idea what is wrong? Thanks, Manfred.

Comment: Is your JIRA server on HTTPS or SSL?

Comment: Please post your code first

Comment: The JIRA server is called via HTTPS

Comment: I just added the code - thanks for your answer.